# How to separate a column to use specific info for another column in R

Tags: r, string, multiple-columns

I have a column with info that looks like this

ATCC_V1V2_27F_338R

Chicken_02_V1V2_27F_338R

.

.

.

ATCC_V5V6_27FYM_338R

Chicken_02_V5V6_27FYM_338R

I want to create 3 additional columns: one with the info that's before the first underscore and name it 'sample type' (e.g., ATTC and Chicken), a second column with the information that starts with V (e.g., V5V6 and V1V2) and name it 'variable region', and a third column with the info before the F and the R (e.g., 27F_338R) and name it 'primer pair'. The info is slightly different from string to string. Any ideas?

Comment: `tidyr::separate_wider_delim(your_data, delim = "", names = c("sample type", "variable region", "primer pair"))`

Comment: Hmmm, looking more it's not exactly a `separate_wider_delim`. If you format your data more nicely (use code formatting with 3 backticks \`\`\` on blank lines before and after the code/data) and also include the desired output explicitly for the sample input, we can help more specifically.